# If $A$ is an orthogonal operator then columns of $M(A)$ forms an orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that $A \in L (n)$ is an orthogonal operator if and only if there exist orthonormal bases $X=\{x_1...x_n\}$, $Y=\{y_1...y_n\}$ of $R^n$ such that the column vectors of
the associated matrix $M (A)$ with respect to those basis, form an orthonormal basis.

I know that
$M(A)=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}A\left(\mathbf{x}_{1}\right) \cdot \mathbf{y}_{1} & A\left(\mathbf{x}_{2}\right) \cdot \mathbf{y}_{1} & \ldots & A\left(\mathbf{x}_{n}\right) \cdot \mathbf{y}_{1} \\ A\left(\mathbf{x}_{1}\right) \cdot \mathbf{y}_{2} & A\left(\mathbf{x}_{2}\right) \cdot \mathbf{y}_{2} & \ldots & A\left(\mathbf{x}_{n}\right) \cdot \mathbf{y}_{2} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ A\left(\mathbf{x}_{1}\right) \cdot \mathbf{y}_{n} & A\left(\mathbf{x}_{2}\right) \cdot \mathbf{y}_{n} & \ldots & A\left(\mathbf{x}_{n}\right) \cdot \mathbf{y}_{n}\end{array}\right)$

and $||A(x_1)||=||y_1||=1$ should i prove that $||(A(x_j)\cdot y_1,...,A(x_j)\cdot y_n)||=1$ for $1\leq j \leq n$ and $(A(x_j)\cdot y_1,...,A(x_i)\cdot y_n) \cdot (A(x_i)\cdot y_1,...,A(x_j)\cdot y_n)=0$  how can i do it? im very stuck thank you!

Comment: What is your definition of $A$ being an orthogonal operator?

Comment: @SammyBlack if $||A(x)||=||x||$

Comment: Hint: $x\cdot y=(\lVert x+y\rVert^2-\lVert x-y\rVert^2)/4$.